# Unable to locate package pdk on debian

Tags: debian, apt, puppet

I am trying to install the external package `pdk` on debian bullseye. Following the [official instructions](https://www.puppet.com/docs/pdk/2.x/pdk_install.html#install-on-debian-or-ubuntu) I executed the following:

```
wget https://apt.puppet.com/puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb
dpkg -i puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb
apt-get update
apt-get install pdk
```

Here are all the steps I did on a fresh `debian:bullseye` docker image:

1. Updating package list and installing wget

```
root@fb976189c8c6:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 Packages [7951 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main arm64 Packages [250 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main arm64 Packages [14.9 kB]
Fetched 8424 kB in 2s (4213 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
root@fb976189c8c6:/# apt-get install wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates libpsl5 openssl publicsuffix
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates libpsl5 openssl publicsuffix wget
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2126 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5853 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 openssl arm64 1.1.1w-0+deb11u1 [837 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 ca-certificates all 20210119 [158 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 libpsl5 arm64 0.21.0-1.2 [57.1 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 wget arm64 1.21-1+deb11u1 [946 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 publicsuffix all 20220811.1734-0+deb11u1 [127 kB]
Fetched 2126 kB in 0s (5603 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package openssl.
(Reading database ... 6656 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openssl_1.1.1w-0+deb11u1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (1.1.1w-0+deb11u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates.
Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates_20210119_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20210119) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpsl5:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpsl5_0.21.0-1.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libpsl5:arm64 (0.21.0-1.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package wget.
Preparing to unpack .../wget_1.21-1+deb11u1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking wget (1.21-1+deb11u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package publicsuffix.
Preparing to unpack .../publicsuffix_20220811.1734-0+deb11u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking publicsuffix (20220811.1734-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libpsl5:arm64 (0.21.0-1.2) ...
Setting up wget (1.21-1+deb11u1) ...
Setting up openssl (1.1.1w-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up publicsuffix (20220811.1734-0+deb11u1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20210119) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 78.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/perl/5.32.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.32.1 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.32 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/perl/5.32 /usr/share/perl/5.32 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
129 added, 0 removed; done.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u7) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

2. Download `puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb`

```
root@fb976189c8c6:/# wget https://apt.puppet.com/puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb
--2023-10-13 07:10:35--  https://apt.puppet.com/puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb
Resolving apt.puppet.com (apt.puppet.com)... 18.173.154.43, 18.173.154.87, 18.173.154.2, ...
Connecting to apt.puppet.com (apt.puppet.com)|18.173.154.43|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11772 (11K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: 'puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb'

puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb                                   100%[===================================================================================================================================================================>]  11.50K  --.-KB/s    in 0.002s

2023-10-13 07:10:36 (4.85 MB/s) - 'puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb' saved [11772/11772]
```

3. Installing `puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb`

```
root@fb976189c8c6:/# dpkg -i puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb
Selecting previously unselected package puppet-tools-release.
(Reading database ... 7074 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb ...
Unpacking puppet-tools-release (1.0.0-9bullseye) ...
Setting up puppet-tools-release (1.0.0-9bullseye) ...
```

4. Updating package list again and trying to install `pdk`

```
root@fb976189c8c6:/# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Get:4 http://apt.puppet.com bullseye InRelease [83.7 kB]
Get:5 http://apt.puppet.com bullseye/puppet-tools arm64 Packages [549 B]
Get:6 http://apt.puppet.com bullseye/puppet-tools all Packages [549 B]
Fetched 84.8 kB in 1s (95.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
root@fb976189c8c6:/# apt-get install pdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pdk
```

After execution of the last command I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package pdk
```

I also cannot find the package `pdk` in the available package list (`apt list`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like the instructions are wrong. I can't find a `pdk` package in the [Debian repositories](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=filename&suite=bookworm&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=pdk). Unless installing `puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb` is supposed to add a repository and that didn't work. What was the output of `dpkg -i puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb`?

Comment: It would also be useful to see the output of `apt-get update` after the package installed successfully.

Comment: I added the output of the commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no arm64 build of the `pdk` package available for buster.  looks like they only publish amd64 builds.  You can see the packages available here

http://apt.puppet.com/pool/bullseye/puppet-tools/p/pdk/index.html

You can attempt to build it yourself or use a different distro, architecture or release that has an arm build available.  I'm not familiar with puppet and its outside the scope of your question, you'll have to refer to puppet documentation as to how to proceed with an arm build.

Comment: I could install the package using an amd64 build, thanks!